# AWK Curly Braces not working

Tags: awk

Trying to run an awk command according to some documentation ([linky](http://zvfak.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-read-bsmap-methylation-ratio.html)).

However, whenever I add {1} or {2} to the awk command as documentation describes (see link above or example below) my search stops working.  Zero results even on gigantic multi-gigabyte files.  Any advice?

### These work

```
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/^CG/)' example
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/..CG/)' example
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/.CG/)' example
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/^..CG/)' example
```

### These don't return anything (even on a 3 gigabyte file)

```
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/.{2}CG/)' example
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/.{1}CG/)' example
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/^.{2}CG/)' example
```

### Full command according to documentation:

```
awk '($3=="-" && $4~/^.{1}CG/ ) || ($3=="+" &&  $4~/^.{2}CG/)' BSMAPexample.txt > CpG.txt
```

### Example dataset

### EDIT (A COLUMN DISAPPEARED WHEN I PASTED INTO STACK EXCHANGE, TYPO FIXED)

> chr   pos strand  context ratio   total_C methy_C CI_lower    CI_upper
>
> chr1  3121589 + CGCGT 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121597 + ATCGG 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121599 + GTCGT 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121605 + CTCGG 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121606 + TGCGC 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121607 + GGCGC 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121611 + CTCGA 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121614 + TACGC 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064
>
> chr1  3121631 + CTCGT 0.000   56  0   0.000   0.064

Comment: You example dataset doesn't have the "+" or "-" strand, so I don't know how the "these work" examples work.

Comment: How come you knew to use `{}` to format your code but forgot to use it a couple of lines later to format your sample input? Anyway, there isn't a single `+` or `-` sign anywhere in your posted sample input so why would you expect `$3=="+"` or `$3=="-"` to match any line?

Answer (score 3):

You have removed some columns from the original sample data.

This is the original data in the link you sent:

```
chr  pos     strand context ratio total_C methy_C CI_lower CI_upper
chr1 3121589 +      CGCGT   0.000 56      0       0.000    0.064
chr1 3121597 +      ATCGG   0.000 56      0       0.000    0.064
chr1 3121599 +      GTCGT   0.000 56      0       0.000    0.064
```

And this is the sample data you posted:

```
chr  pos     strand context ratio total_C methy_C CI_lower CI_upper
chr1 3121589 CGCGT  0.000   56    0       0.000 0.064
chr1 3121597 ATCGG  0.000   56    0       0.000 0.064
chr1 3121599 GTCGT  0.000   56    0       0.000 0.064
```

This is a problem for an expression like this:

```
awk '($3=="+" &&  $4~/.{2}CG/)' example
```

Which expects a + symbol in the third column (`$3`, inexisting in your data) and some repetitions of CG in the fourth column (`$4` which seems to be located in position number 3). It won't match any line in your file.

If you modify the expression to refer to the proper column (`$3`) and forget the + sign since it does not appear in your data, you will get to match lines in your file.

```
$ awk '($3~/.{2}CG/)' example
chr1 3121589 CGCGT 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121597 ATCGG 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121599 GTCGT 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121605 CTCGG 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121606 TGCGC 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121607 GGCGC 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121611 CTCGA 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121614 TACGC 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
chr1 3121631 CTCGT 0.000 56 0 0.000 0.064
$
```

Actually all lines in the *example* file have 2 characters before the CG (**CG*). Only the header will be skipped.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  that column disappeared when I copied and pasted into stack exchange.   Not sure how or why.   Here is a screenshot.  http://i63.tinypic.com/2a7d3f9.jpg  Column exists and I still can't get it to work.                         .

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The missing column happened when I copied and pasted into stack exchange.  I still can't get it to work.

[linkY](http://i63.tinypic.com/2a7d3f9.jpg)               <-------- see screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  I used gawk and --posix

```
gawk --posix '($3=="-" && $4~/^.{1}CG/ ) || ($3=="+" &&  $4~/^.{2}CG/)'
```

Works just fine now.